# My number keeps getting truncated by 3 digits in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have some code which multiples an item's price by its quantity, but that number ($qtyprice) keeps getting truncated by 3 digits every single time even though there is no function being called on the end product. Any help is appreciated.

```js
for ($x = 0; $x < count($carmodel); $x++) {
  $qtyprice = $prices[$x] * $qty[$x];
  $html .= '<tr>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:20px; width:450px;text-align: left;font-family:calibri;font-size:10px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;">'.ucfirst($exhaust[$x]).', '.$carmake[$x].', '.$carmodel[$x].', '.$caritem[$x].'</td>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;width:55px;text-align: center;font-family:calibri;font-size:10px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;">'.$qty[$x].'</td>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;width:65px;text-align: center;font-family:calibri;font-size:10px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;">'.$prices[$x].'</td>
              <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;width:65px;text-align: right;font-family:calibri;font-size:10px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;">'.$qtyprice.'</td>  
            </tr>';

}
```

[image]

Comment: I see when you print out `$prices[$x]`, the value has a comma in it, so it is a string. Try stripping those commas away

Comment: You're right, i had called number_format earlier on. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that your unit price is stored with a format, so when you multiply, PHP is trying the best to convert it to a number, hence your number is truncated. If you get the price from somewhere, you can use `str_replace()`

```
$price = (int) str_replace(',', '', $price);
```

Since you said that you use `number_format()` before, I suggest that you only use number_format when print the value out to avoid the confusion.